# Where can I get or generate appkey.c for Spotify?

Tags: spotify, libspotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am trying to run the examples for CocoaLibSpotify, but I need the file `appkey.c` with the API credentials. Where can I get this, or how do I generate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Spotify premium account. I think once you have one you can go to the Spotify Developer site and request and download an app key. https://devaccount.spotify.com/my-account/keys/